# "Join" within the same table

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I'm creating a program that holds a members list using camelot (which uses sqlalchemy ORM). There will be people that are married to each other which means a one to one relationship within the same table. This is a simplified version of the Person class:

```
class Person( Entity ):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    firstname = Column( Unicode(30), nullable = False )
    lastname = Column( Unicode(30), nullable = False )
    member_no = Column( Integer )
    marital_status = Column( Unicode(15) )
    marriage_date = Column( Date() )
    married_to = ... # Should be one to one with self
```

I tried doing this:

```
married_to = relationship("Person", uselist=False, backref="persons")
married_to_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('persons.id'))
```

But it fails with:

> InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't
>   proceed with initialization of other mappers.  Original exception was:
>   Person.married_to and back-reference Person.persons are both of the
>   same direction .  Did you mean to set remote_side
>   on the many-to-one side ?

How could I join within the same table, or is this the wrong approach I'm using. And could it be done so if I join Person A with B, then Person B is automatically joined with A (as a marriege work - it both ways...)

I hope I'm making myself clear. :-/

Comment: Sigh....  1-to-1?  Why must marriage imply monogamy?

Comment: I thought of that when creating this. But according to the law of my country polygamy is not allowed. So I guess I change my software if the law changes :-p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't expect that I'm answering your question, but wanted to point out that because of the bidirectional nature of marriage between two persons, you may want to consider a separate table to hold just marriage, with the primary key consisting of two `person_id` references.  You could also entertain the idea of keeping a history in this table by including 'start' and 'end' dates =)

Answer (score 3):

You want an Adjacentcy List Relationship. Here's the
[documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/relationships.html#adjacency-list-relationships).

> The relationship() configuration here works in the same way as a “normal” one-to-many relationship, with the exception that the “direction”, i.e. whether the relationship is one-to-many or many-to-one, is assumed by default to be one-to-many. To establish the relationship as many-to-one, an extra directive is added known as remote_side, which is a Column or collection of Column objects that indicate those which should be considered to be “remote

Maybe try:

```
married_to = relationship("Person", remote_side=[id])
```

Answer (score 1):

if this is all within the same table, you can't use foreign keys. foreign keys are, by definition, keys from other tables.

i would use a `married_to` column, so that people married to each other have their partners' respective `id`. Then your query would become very simplified.